# How to set GraalVM 17 as the default JDK in Manjaro Linux 23?

Tags: java, archlinux, graalvm, manjaro

I'm using Manjaro 23, and I want to set GraalVM 17 as the default JDK.

I'm an Ubuntu user, and I used the `update-alternatives java --config` command to install third-party JDKs.

- I installed GraalVM 17 by downloading the package from the official source.
- I created a symbolic link from my GraalVM installation to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-graalvm`.
- I tried using the `archlinux-java` command to set the default JDK, but it returned an error message saying that `/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-graalvm` is not a valid directory.
- I also tried using the commands `archlinux-java set-default` and `archlinux-java-set-default`, but these commands do not exist.

  Is there a similar command to `update-alternatives` in Manjaro that I can use?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem by deleting the first symbolic link I had created. I created a folder in `/lib/jvm` called `java-17-graalvm` and then it showed up without problems when I ran `archlinux-java` and I was able to do `set` without problems.